# Impossible to create/format install Windows 7 on unpartitioned HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am going nuts reinstalling Windows 7 on one of those Acer aspire all-in-one... The original OS (Windows Professional x64) was not starting, after the initial screen the BIOS was prompted. So

- Step 1: I tried to access the system partition and reinstall everything but could not get to that point
- Step 2: I set the BIOS to  native IDE and I tried to insert my original copy of Windows Professional and do a clean installation, but it does not allow me to format/create another partition for the installation mask
- Step 3: I tried to install Ubuntu and I cleaned the whole hard drive, I was getting an error at some point during installation so I decided to get back to Windows
- Step 4: Windows 7 again, at the disk screen of the Windows installation I opened the prompt and played around with `DISKPART`...

  - I listed the disk and the HD was disk 0.
  - I selected disk 0.
  - I `CLEAN`ed disk 0 successfully.
  - I tried to create a `CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY` but gave an error about the cache being corrupt and the disk not being up-to-date (after I tried to create a partition in disk 0 it disappeared when I try `LIST DISK` and I have to restart before it can list DISK 0 again. `RESCAN` did not work).
  - Tried `CLEAN ALL` (2 hours) and succeeded.
  - Tried again to create a primary partition and failed, same errors
  - Tried to install my old copy of Windows XP  Pro and it seems to work, it creates a partition, formats (only "quick" worked, slow mode was at 0% and after 1 hour so I stopped), it starts installing and at around 90% installation it says it could not copy a file and it stops.
  - Back on Windows 7 again, it says that the hard drive has 490+GB unpartitioned but won't create a partition and format.
  - I tried again with `DISKPART` as I thought I messed up the MBR when I installed Ubuntu, so I did [all of these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20201121061916/https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html).

The errors were:

- On `bootsect`:

  > the system partiton was not found, Data error cyclic redundancy check
- on `bootrec /FixMbr`:

  > A device attached to the system is not functioning

But it did not work, and I still can not partiton/format/install on a blank HD. I tried some bootable clean disk tool and started an infinite loop on the same errors.

The BIOS setting are: SATA: native IDE. If I set AHCL (or something like that) it does not load the HD and the DVD. Quick start/quiet start: disabled.

Are there any other options or tools I can try before I change the HD (that is my last option)?

Comment: Why not use the gui interface of Windows setup to delete and create partitions?

Comment: Try using GParted from a bootable USB/CD. However CRC error doesn't fill me with confidence that your drive is ok. Be sure to test thoroughly with the drive manufacturer's utility before install the OS and saving your data to it.

Comment: the user interface wont create/ format/ partition the hard drive

Comment: After changing the partition table like the command `clean` does, you may need to reboot the installer for changes to be detected.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have a hardware issue or, the default drivers provided with the install disks are not the precise ones required for the hardware.

Check the manufacturer procedure for doing a clean install and/or search for manufacturer certified drivers for the IDE/SATA controller to load at the appropriate step during setup.